# Installing Linux on Apple M1 (Mac Mini)

Tags: linux, system-installation, kernel-panic, apple

I would like to install Linux on a Mac Mini with an Apple M1 processor.

So far, I have tried the tutorial at https://corellium.com/blog/linux-m1 (I have tried both the USB and the NVME option). However, when I boot the system after the installation, I get the following error message:

```
[ 2.107062] Freeing unused kernel nemory: 4736K
[ 2.108173] platform regulatory.0: Direct firmware load for regulatory.db failed with error -2
[ 2.109071] cfg80211: failed to load regulatory.db
[ 2.131675] Checked W+X mappings: passed, no W+X pages found 
[ 2.133484] Run /init as init process
[ 2.243825] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=2815, bcdDevice= 7.01
…
[ 4.121920] usb 3-1.4: Manufacturer: Realtek
[ 4.125169] usb 3-1.4: SerialNumber: 000001
Failed to locate root partition!
[11.157396] Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000100
[11.159288] CPU: 7 PID: 1 Comm: init Not tainted 5.11.0-rc4+ #192
[11.161180] Hardware name: Mac Mini Late 2020 (DT)
[11.163056] Call trace:
[11.164899]   dump_backtrace+0x0/0x210
[11.166749]   show_stack+0x2c/0x80
[11.168575]   dump_stack+0xd4/0x12c
[11.170394]   panic+0x170/0x398
[11.172194]   do exit+0x970/0xa70
[11.173993]   do_group_exit+0x4c/0xb0
[11.175797]   __arm64_sys_exit_group+0x24/0x30
[11.177602]   do_el0_svc+0x78/0x120 
[11.179392]   el0_svc+0x18/0x20
[11.181169]   el0_sync_handler+0x8c/0xc0 
[11.182925]   el0_sync+0x140/0x180
[11.184662] SMP: stopping secondary CPUs
[11.186419] Kernel Offset: disabled 
[11.188128] CPU features: 0x09800017,48000820
[11.189843] Memory Limit: none
[11.191548] --- [end Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000100 ]---
```

How can this error be solved? Is there a better way to install Linux on an M1 machine than with the Corellium tutorial?

Note: I'm aware that currently not all components of the M1 are supported by Linux.

Comment: It seems the kernel cannot find the root-filesystem. What are your linux kernel command-line parameters? You should specify following parameters: `root=<ROOT-FS-DEVICE> rootfstype=<ROOT-FS-TYPE> rootwait` - `<ROOT-FS-DEVICE>` and `<ROOT-FS-TYPE>` are placeholders. Also make sure your kernel is able to detect the mass storage device where the root-filesystem is located and your kernel supports the specified filesystem type.

Comment: @paladin I'm using the parameters from the Corellium image. The cmdline.txt in the system-boot partition contains the following: `dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 root=LABEL=writable rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait fixrtc quiet splash`

Comment: Is the ext4 filesystem of your root partition labeled as writable? You may label it using `e2label <DEVICE> <VOLUME-LABEL>`

Comment: The M1 Linux port is very far from being ready and complete. If you're not going to develop it, it's not worth even trying it.

Comment: @paladin Yes, the label of the root partition in the Corellium image is "writable".

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov As I pointed out in the last sentence of my question, I'm aware that the port is not complete. For my use case, it does not need to be complete.

Comment: If you need to run Linux on M1 you could simply use virtualization.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov No, virtualization doesn't work for my use case. I need direct access to hardware performance counters (among other things).

Comment: Has your kernel drivers for your mass storage controller, aka SATA/SCSI/NVMe? Is your kernel able to detect your mass storage device? May you please provide a full kernel log?

Comment: @paladin My kernel is the one from the link in my question. How can I generate/access a full kernel log?

Comment: Usually you could use a serial port for debugging, but this might not be possible on your apple computer because it has no serial port. https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/serial-console.html . Another approach would be to use a high speed high-resolution camera and try to take a movie of the boot process and using video editing software to manual create the boot log, but this may not a complete log.

Comment: PS you might try to use a USB serial port